# One time json serialization with type info in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

We can set serialization settings via JsConfig in ServiceStack.

```
JsConfig.IncludeTypeInfo = true;
```

But we want to user Json serializing without "Type Info" except one place.
So how can we serialize with type info at there.

I think we need optional config parameter:

```
JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(x,**JsConfig**)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a scope for only the place you need the type information:

```
using (JsConfig.With(new Config { IncludeTypeInfo = true }))
{
    var json = new DTO().ToJson();
}
```